# Force Contributors to add Tags via edit-tags.php

Tags: admin, tags

I need to be able to stop contributors to the website from adding new Tags when they create or edit a Post in WP.

The reason is that I need them to enter an additional field at the same time which I can achieve via ACF in the edit-tags.php page.

However, no matter what I do I can't seem to stop users entering new tags on the tag section on the new post or edit post page(s). They should still be able to select from existing tags when creating/editing a post, but to enter one they should be forced to use the edit-tags.php.

Here's what I've got so far (edited after discussions below):

```
function disallow_insert_term($term, $taxonomy) {
  if( strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php') || strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post.php') ) {
    return new WP_Error(
      'disallow_insert_term',
      __('Your role does not have permission to add terms to this taxonomy')
    );
  } elseif (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/edit-tags.php')) {
      return $term;
  } else {
      return $term;
  }
}
add_filter('pre_insert_term', 'disallow_insert_term', 10, 2);
```

The problem is that any new "if" tests I try to do within the function end up being ignored and just the final task runs. So, in the above, the user can enter new tags on any page. If I remove the "elseif" function you can't enter any tags into the site at all.

I've tried using get_current_screen() and $wp->request to get the URL but just run into the same problem.

Comment: hmmm there's no check in your code for wether the user is a contributor or not. Also, filters always return something, but if neither of your if statements match, then nothing is returned and `null` is passed to the next filter along, you should **always** return something at the end

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom, I have tried it without the "elseif" part and had the "return $term" at the end, but that just allows users to add tags from any page. should add, the 'contributor' part is less important.

Comment: I don't mean my comment as a solution, whether it's the cause of your problem or not, it is still a problem. Filters must **always** return something. If neither of your `if` statements are true, nothing is returned. Add `return $term;` to the end of your function ( even if it does not solve your problem ). Think of it this way, what you have right now is the same as adding `else { return null; }` to the end, which will cause broken-ness somewhere. Also, that `elseif` is the same as an `if` since the first `if` returns anyway

Comment: To demonstrate the point, what happens if a term gets created by a plugin behind the scenes, e.g. the WP Core nav menu interface, but then your filter runs, but we aren't on the new posts screen, and we aren't on `edit-tags.php`. Neither of the `if` statements will run, and nothing will be returned, so the final term to be saved is `null`, making it impossible to create navigation menus on the site. _Filters must always return something_, yours does not